# How to create TabWidget inside a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image]I need to create a TabWidget inside a Fragment. It should look like as in the attached image. The content of each Tab should be in a separate Fragment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to visit [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)